# Openshift on AWS is automatically allowing container to be deployed as root user

Tags: openshift

I tried to deploy library/cassandra image cassandra container in Sandbox Openshift cluster but it threw me this error  in pod logs,

**"Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option."**

When I checked the container description, I could see that SCC is set to Restricted...So looks like in Sandbox openshift, SCC "Restricted" is set for "Default" Service account by default..

But in AWS when I tried to install openshift with installer option, I didnt face this error with same library/cassandra image..

Looks like default Service account is not by default associated with "Restricted" SCC...

could someone clarify what is the difference in Sandbox environment which throws this error? and How can I set the same config in AWS  openshift so that default Service account can be associated with restricted SCC?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your specific environment, but from the error message I suspect it's being triggered by the GROUP=0, not user=0.

To confirm:

$ oc get pods (whatever) -o yaml | grep openshift.io/scc

This will show you which SCC admitted the pod into the cluster.  It should be "restricted" based on what you said.  If so, then we've got some good evidence that it's just the group.

Next, you can look for something like this:

$ oc rsh (podname) id -a
uid=1000640000(1000640000) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000640000

UID (user) is in the expected billion+ range defined in the namespace annotation.  GID (group) is zero.

With that in place, you can either ignore the error, knowing it's own group=0 that's in place, or you can set a securityContext for your pod (or container) to specify a different gid.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that "default" project has different set of permissions so even a container with user id 0 can be deployed in default namespace..
In Sandbox cluster, the project is dev or stage so it works with correct security level..